# how to change size of guitar chord diagrams?

Tags: music

For fun and profit I'm typesetting the first 4 chords the book I'm reading to learn the guitar recommends practicing, however I find hard to change the size of the diagrams, so they are very visible on the paper and I don't have to squint my eyes.

Here is my code so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{gchords}
\usepackage{guitarchordschemes}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\setchordscheme{
  x-unit=10cm,
  y-unit=20cm,
}
\def\numfrets{5}

\chords{
  \chord{t}{o,f2p2,f3p2,o,o,o}{E menor}
  \chord{t}{x,o,f2p2,f3p2,f1p1,o}{A mayor}
}
\chords{
  \chord{t}{x,f3p3,f2p2,o,f1p1,o}{C mayor}
  \chord{t}{x,x,f3p3,f2p2,f1p1,o}{F mayor 7}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are using two distinct packages `\setchordscheme` is from `guitarchordschemes` but `\chords` and `\chord` are (probably) from `gchords`. The options from the former naturally don't influence the latter.

Comment: @cgnieder well, now I understand, but sadly I'm not capable of figuring out how to change any settings for `gchords`. EDIT: Just noticed that the PDF I was reading only groups a series of packages and that full documentation for gchords can be found here http://mirrors.ucr.ac.cr/CTAN/graphics/gchords/gchords_doc.pdf

Comment: BTW every package that is distributed with the main distributions has its own CTAN page: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/gchords Also you have the manual probably already on your computer, try `texdoc gchords` on the command line

Answer (score 1):

According to gchords documentation there is a command called `\mediumchords` which is a pre-defines a diagram size, for my use case, <strike>this works for me</strike> it is still too small on print meaning that some experimentation must be done.

You should check it's documentation: http://mirrors.ucr.ac.cr/CTAN/graphics/gchords/gchords_doc.pdf